# Cannot read docker container logs: Permission denied

Tags: docker

When issuing the `docker log <container>` command, I am getting the following error:

```
[root@Infra-1 ~]# docker logs gitlab-redis
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/redis': Permission denied
```

`gitlab-redis` is a container that has exited.

In fact, the directory does not exist at all:

```
[root@Infra-1 ~]# ls /var/lib/redis
ls: cannot access /var/lib/redis: No such file or directory
```

I suppose that `docker log` is looking in the wrong location. Could it possibly have been misconfigured? Where should I check?

Comment: Is the gitlab-redis image based on https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redis/blob/master/Dockerfile? Can you do a `docker inspect` to check its data?

Comment: @VonC It seems so. This is the image file I pulled `https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/redis/~/dockerfile/`

Comment: By the way, the issue was caused by SELinux. https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/issues/530

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `docker logs` is working, the output of the logs is `chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/redis': Permission denied`.

`/var/lib/redis` is inside the container, not on the host.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. `/var/lib/redis/` seems to be a mount point in the container: `docker run --name gitlab-redis -d     --volume /srv/docker/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis     sameersbn/redis:latest`  For some reason, this mount point cannot be created.